# Is there a way to remove specific elements in an array using numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to remove specific elements in an array using [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), boolean mask (or any other function) that meet certain criteria such as conditionals on that data type?, this by using **numpy** methods.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.chisquare(6, 10)
```

```
array([4.61518458, 4.80728541, 4.59749491, 3.44053946, 5.52507358,
       7.97092747, 2.01946678, 6.26877508, 3.68286537, 2.06759469])`
```

Now for *test* purposes I would like to know if I can use some **numpy** function to remove all elements that are divisible by the given value `k`

```py
>>> np.delete(arr, 1, 0)
[4.61518458 4.59749491 3.44053946 5.52507358 7.97092747 2.01946678
 6.26877508 3.68286537 2.06759469]
```

the `delete(arr, 1, 0)` call only removes the value at that position, is there a way to delete multiple values based on anonymous function `lambda` or a condition like the one I mentioned above?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is part of numpy's magic indexing.  You can use comparison operator or the `apply` function to produce an array of booleans, with True for the ones to keep and False for the ones to toss.  So, for example, to keep all the elements less than 5::

```
selections = array < 5
array = array[selections]
```

That will only keep the elements where `selections` is True.

Of course, since all your values are floats, they aren't going to be divisible by an integer `k`, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

For doing such division, based on the answer of **Tim**:

```
k = 6  # a number
array = array[array % k == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at floating point division [and will therefore be subject to numerical limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), there should be no expectation that the result of the division will be *perfect*. Instead, I would suggest that you accept removing all the numbers that are *almost* divisble by `k`.

For your problem I would set a threshold and use [`np.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
arr[np.logical_and(arr % k > threshold, (k - (arr % k) > thresold)]
```

**Explanation**

Consider the following problem:

```
k = 1.0000002300000000450001000101
x = np.array([k * i for i in range(1,10)] + [0.5,])
#array([1.00000023, 2.00000046, 3.00000069, 4.00000092, 5.00000115,
#       6.00000138, 7.00000161, 8.00000184, 9.00000207, 0.5])
```

In theory, all the numbers but the last one (`0.5`) should be divisible by `k` exactly. In reality, numerical precision limits that capability (if you really want to dig into why, I'd refer to the link above on [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html))

```
np.where(x%k==0)
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)
x[x%k==0]
#array([1.00000023, 2.00000046, 3.00000069, 4.00000092, 6.00000138,
#       8.00000184])
```

We've missed a few that we would like to have been caught (`x[4]`, `x[6]` and `x[8]`, with values of `5*k` `6*k` and `9*k`). If we look at the modular division itself, we see that the missed numbers are *almost* `0` or *almost* `k` (we expect the last one since `0.5%k==0.5`):

```
x[x%k!=0]%k
#array([1.00000023e+00, 4.44089210e-16, 1.00000023e+00, 5.00000000e-01])
```

So the best we can do is find a work around where we look for cases that are *close enough*. Noting that the differences above are O(`2**-51`), we can use `2**-50` as our threshold in this case but for practical purposes we can probably be a bit more lenient.

You also mention you want to eliminate the values that are divisible, so we want to keep the values where `x%k > threshold` and `k-x%k > threshold`:

```
threshold = 2**-50
x[np.logical_and((x % k) > threshold, (k - (x % k)) > threshold)]
#array([0.5])
```

If you wanted to keep them, then you'd use the opposite inequalities and use [`np.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
x[np.logical_or((x % k) < threshold, (k - (x % k)) < threshold)]
#array([1.00000023, 2.00000046, 3.00000069, 4.00000092, 5.00000115,
#       6.00000138, 7.00000161, 8.00000184, 9.00000207])
```